# Why is email sent from my AWS SES server cannot arrive on corporate-domain email, but arrive on mail service such as Gmail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, email-server, email-bounces, e-mailrelay

The summary:

- email from SES did not arrive at user's corp domain email.
- email from SES arrives at my corp domain email but is hosted at Gmail.
- email from my private Gmail arrives at user's corp domain email.
- email received by receiving MTA with status 250 (AWS rep told me it means email received correctly at the receiving MTA).
- receiving MTA responded by putting the email in queue for delivery, instead of directly delivering the message to the recipient's inbox.

---

In the app we develop, we use AWS SES to send emails.

From the configurations, the log shows that it has already passed SPF, DKIM, and DMARC. It also already uses TLS (SSL).

[image: AWS Log]

The email was sent to the user's corporate domain email, and cc-ed to my own email which is also a corporate domain email but hosted on Gmail.

The email arrived in my inbox, but did not arrive to user's inbox.

After that, I also sent an email from my own Gmail, to the user's corporate domain email, and they received the email.

This eliminates the possibility that the email is bouncing because it's full.

I then reached out to AWS support. They pulled the log dive, and inform me that the email indeed left the SES successfully, and was received by "receiving MTA" (Mail Transfer Agent).

But the log showed that the receiving MTA put the email into "Queued for delivery" status, instead of instantly delivered.

The AWS support informed me that the next step is to check with the receiving MTA, why it's put into the queue, instead of being delivered to the user's inbox. But this isn't possible to do, because we can't possibly ask random corporate so we can inspect their mail service system.

[image: AWS rep log dive]

Is there anything I still haven't configured properly here? Why does email from Gmail arrives but not the email from my server?

Comment: The 250 response is more than a mere confirmation of successful transmission - as per [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-6.1) is is an acceptance of *responsibility* for delivering it. Anyone losing messages after that better have a good excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inbound and outbound email is always queued for delivery and then processed and delivered to the mailbox (inbound) or sent to the destination server or next hop (outbound). There's nothing abnormal about that.

If the recipient server accepted the message then the only thing you can do is reach out to one of the affected recipients and have them ask their mail administrator to perform a message trace to determine what happened to your email.